# Renaming in /etc/fstab

Tags: filesystems, migration

I have a question about a disk which is almost full in my Ubuntu server.

```
$ df -Th
/dev/sdc  ext4 1008G 884G 73G 93% /mnt
/dev/sdd1 ext4 1.5T  69M  1.5T   1% /newmnt

Web application storage : /mnt/var/www/***
SVN repository storage : /mnt/var/repository/svn
```

The web apps and the repository is residing in /mnt which is almost full and my IT team had problems extending the disk and rather provided me with a new partition /newmnt. So I will have to move all the contents of /mnt to the new partition /newmnt.

There are two concerns for me now :

- The repository table in the MYSQL database is having hard coded values of the repository location. For ex - '/mnt/var/repository/svn/example_repository'. There are many repositories and all of them are stored in the DB as hard-coded values.
- Apache configuration is also having the hard coded variables for the web app and the SVN authentication.

There are too many web apps connected to many repositories so I cannot afford to change them as it is time consuming.

So coming to the question, my plan is to copy all the contents of /mnt to /newmnt. Later editing /etc/fstab and changing /mnt to /mnt_old and /newmnt to /mnt and reboot the server.

Will the renamed structure work ? Will my web apps and repositories still work like before?

Comment: yes, that layer of abstraction between the name of your mount point and wherever it maps to is the beauty and the whole point... which sound like you specifically need `/mnt` for things to work...  wherever the  `/mnt` folder gets mapped to such as`/dev/sdd1` or `/dev/sdz4` and whatever those storage devices are be it a hard disk, or SSD, or usb flash memory or somewhere across a network generally does not matter with regards to software configurations working except maybe for speed and timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

To a more ellaborate answer.

I would

1. rename in `/etc/fstab` first (change `/mnt` to `/mnt_old` and leave `/newmnt` )
2. reboot host

   2.1 if you can prevent application from running the better

   2.2 if no, that shoudn't be a problem since `/mnt` is empty
3. do the copying
4. edit `/etc/fstab` (change`/newmnt` to `/mnt` ), you still have `/mnt_old` as backup.
5. reboot.

please note :

- don't forget to create mount point (aka directory).
- kernel have no need of `/etc/fstab` to dismount active mount point.